# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException while Inserting the values in arrayList

Tags: java

```
javax.faces.FacesException: #{scheduleBean.insert()}: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

Code:

```
 public void insert(){

       for(ScheduleMaster v:arrayList1){

           arrayList1.add(mm.i, v); 
       }           
       List<ScheduleMaster>temp1=new ArrayList<ScheduleMaster>();
       temp1=arrayList1;
       System.out.println("Coming Insert");
       Iterator<ScheduleMaster>itr=temp1.iterator();
         while(itr.hasNext()){
             ScheduleMaster s=itr.next();
             s.setServiceCode(serviceCode);
             s.setServiceName(serviceName);
             s.setVessalCode(vessalCode);
             s.setVessalName(vessalName);
             s.setVoyage(voyage);
             s.setPortCode(portCode);
             s.setPortName(portName);
             s.setTerminalCode(terminalCode);
             s.setTerminalName(terminalName);
             s.setEta(eta);
             s.setEtaTimes(etaTimes);
             s.setEtd(etd);
             s.setEtdTimes(etdTimes);
             s.setBound(bound);
             s.setAta(ata);
             s.setAtaTimes(ataTimes);
             s.setAtd(atd);
             s.setAtdTimes(atdTimes);
             arrayList1.add(s);                        

       } 

   }
```

Comment: This is not a well defined question, only a stacktrace and a code snippet. And also it seems a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

`temp1` and `arrayList1` is the reference to the same object. And you cannot iterate over an object and change it while iteration.

So you have to clone the object and then you can iterate over the clone and change the original.

```
  List<ScheduleMaster>temp1=new ArrayList<ScheduleMaster>();
  for(ScheduleMaster v:arrayList1){

       arrayList1.add(mm.i, v); 
       temp1.add(mm.i, v); 
   }
```